# Finding the common value in N number of arrays

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have `n` number of arrays and I want to work out if there is a common value in these arrays. If I knew the number of arrays I could do something like:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [2,4,5]
c = [2,6,7]

x = a & b & c

x == [2]
```

However, this isn't possible if you don't know the number of arrays. So far I've come up with this:

```
array_of_integers = [[1,2,3],[2,4,5]....]
values = []
array_of_integers.each_with_index do |array, index|
  values = if index.zero?
          array
        else
          values & array
        end
end
# `values` will be an array of common values
```

However, this doesn't seem very efficient. Is there a better way?

Comment: I don't think your method works.

Comment: @SagarPandya can you explain why? Seems to work for the specs I've written so far. Igor Drozdov's answer is a much better solution though.

Comment: In your example using array `[[1,2,3],[2,4,5]]` I'm getting `values #=> []`

Comment: @mylescc (1) you never add anything to the `values` array (2) `ids` – being a local variable in the block's scope – will always be `nil` at the beginning of each iteration. Maybe your actual code looks different.

Comment: Ah sorry, my bad. I copied from my codebase but forgot to change all the variable names. I'll update my example. Thanks!

Comment: Though the use of `reduce` is preferred, one could use recursion: `def recurse(arr); arr.size == 1 ? arr.first: arr.first & recurse(arr.drop(1)); end; recurse([a,b,c]) #=> [2]`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> However, this isn't possible if you don't know the number of arrays.

Actually, [Enumerable#reduce](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) can help with it:

```
[[1,2,3], [2,4,5], [2,6,7]].reduce(&:&) # => [2]
```

`&:&` looks interesting, but it's just:

```
[[1,2,3], [2,4,5], [2,6,7]].reduce { |memo, el| memo & el } # => [2]
```

Or it's also possible to do it as @Jagdeep suggested:

```
[[1,2,3], [2,4,5], [2,6,7]].reduce(:&) # => [2]
```

Comment: OR `[[1,2,3], [2,4,5], [2,6,7]].reduce(:&)`

Comment: Looking at the source code for `&` it seems as if it [returns early](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/e82226953f5f2a30f19cbeb7149dd08001836ce4/array.c#L4228) for `[1, 2, 3] & []` but not for `[] & [1, 2, 3]`. Is there an optimization missing?

Comment: @Stefan: Looks that way. By the way, [JRuby has the early return for both](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/jruby/RubyArray.java#L3459-L3461) while [Rubinius has it for neither](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/core/array.rb#L364-L373).

Comment: @JörgWMittag indeed, I've opened a [pull request](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/pull/1938)

Comment: @Stefan, if `reduce` should short-circuit when its receiver is an array of arrays and its argument is `:&`, then presumably it should do the same (for the same receiver) when its argument is `:-`. If the receiver were an array of numbers, should it short-circuit when its argument is `:*` or `:/`? Perhaps we could come up with other examples. Could that be why `reduce` does not short-circuit at all?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I don't think `reduce` should make any such assumptions. And it's hard (if not impossible) to short-circuit a method chain. IMO array manipulation methods that can work on an arbitrary number of arrays (like intersection and concatenation) should be (optimized) class methods, or at least there should be a class method variant, e.g. `Array.concat(a1, a2, ...)`.